# Free up some space in linux system

Tags: command-line, networking

Here is the image of the system,  its full that'why mysql is not working,  any idea how to free up some space from recovery command window ,
Without deleting the core usefull data ? Help appreciated [image: space is full]

Comment: You can see dev/sda6 is full

Comment: Use the `du` command to figure out the biggest space hog. Also check /var/log for a runaway logfile.